# PHP Script to truncate table (shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory)

Tags: php, cron, truncate

I have a php script above public_html folder, which I call via a cron job in cPanel to truncate 2 tables.
It works fine in one of my VPS, but on the other one outputs this error:

> shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access
>   parent directories: No such file or directory job-working-directory:
>   error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent
>   directories: No such file or directory

Any clue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give a better answer without knowing a lot of additional data, but I came across the same error with PHP and it may have the same root cause.

Here is the clue that you were looking for:
If your script is entering a directory that is then deleted, this is the error that occurs.

My PHP script was exec'ing several commands. Some of these created directories and cd'ed in. At the end of the PHP script it removed all of these created directories.

The issue is that the author of the PHP used chdir at one point instead of cd'ing within the exec. When the chdir'ed directory was deleted, PHP's exec calls were using a working directory that did not exist and this error was thrown each time another exec call was used. Removing the chdir and using cd's within exec'ed scripts solved the issue